# Python - 'str' object is not callable when calling from a class

Tags: python, appium

I have a class file named resource.py, so the file is like :

```
class android_resource:

        element = 'wd.find_element_by_id'
        accept_terms_and_conditions = "com.testapp.mobile.app:id/first_launch_wizard_agree_btn"

r = android_resource()
```

I am calling the variables in another file called scripts.py :

```
if 'Agree'in html_source:
    r.element(r.accept_terms_and_conditions).click()
time.sleep(5)
```

But when I run this I am getting error like : `'str' object is not callable`

Where I am wrong ?

Comment: You need to tell us what you are actually trying to do. `r.element` is a string, you can't call it.

Comment: Did you mean: `element =  wd.find_element_by_id()` ?

Comment: @cdarke - Yes I mean that

Answer (score 0):

```
r.element(r.accept_terms_and_conditions)
```

attempts to call the function `r.element`, which in reality is a `str`.

Depending on what you want to do, you need to alter your code.

Comment: Yea, So r.element is really a function "webdriver.find_elelment_by_id", so its calling a function which as a element as r.accept_terms_and_conditions